# How to plot multiple location in google maps using url address?

Tags: iphone, google-maps

As title, how to do that?

to get the direction of two point we can do like 
    http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=40.1212,22.333&daddr=40.222,22.333&z=17"

then how can i plot multiple location using this method by URL address?

Answer (score 0):

You just tack on "to: newloc" to daddr.

E.g.

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=1600+Pennsylvania+Ave&daddr=100+Constitution+Ave+NE%20to:Lincoln+Memorial
```